# how to clean text for nlp containg '[]'

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I have this dataframe 'data_clean' for nlp where on 'louis' you can see the transcripts has [rock music playing][audience cheering]. How can i remove the paranthesis '[]' to clean the text?

[image: ss]

Comment: Please don't post images of text; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas has many bound string methods, which can operate on an entire column.
One of which, is the ability to replace unwanted characters with '', which is equivalent to removing them
Check it out:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(a=['abc]', 'def']))
>>> df
      a
0  abc]
1   def
>>> df['a'].str.replace(']', '')
0    abc
1    def
Name: a, dtype: object
```

The general solution would be to create an array of unwanted characters `a = '[](){}'` and iterate over them, for each one perform the above.